# Please help translate this sentence. 請求する行為によって時効を中断しない限り,

Tags: translation

Cited passage:

> 学生時代に末弘(厳太郎)先生から民法の講義をきいたとき「時効」という制度について次のように説明されたのを覚えています。金を借りて催促さ れないのをいいことにして、ネコババをきめこむ不心得者がトクをして、気の弱い善人の貸し手が結局損をするという結果になるのはずいぶん不人情な話のよう に思われるけれども、この規定の根拠には、権利の上に長くねむっている者は民法の保護に値しないという趣旨も含まれている、というお話だったのです。いま 考えてみると、**請求する行為によって時効を中断しない限り**、たんに自分は債権者であるという位置に安住していると、ついには債権を喪失するというロジック のなかには、一民法の法理にとどまらないきわめて重大な意味がひそんでいるように思われます。

(丸山眞男)
Source: https://ameblo.jp/knowledge184-columnist/entry-11166425820.html

I think the overage passage is saying that if one doesn't protect his rights, then those rights might be loss. Now, I don't understand the highlighted sentence meaning and usage.

請求する行為によって means [by the act of claiming (your money back)], while 時効を中断しない限り means [as long as it's not breaking the legal/valid period] right?

So how does it all fit in with the latter part of the sentence. To me, it seems like he's protecting his rights but then finally he loses it (ついには債権を喪失する). Please help translate.

日本語でも英語でも大丈夫、教えてください。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

簡単にすると「請求する行為によって時効を中断しない限り、ついには債権を喪失する。」となります。「しない限り」は、英語でunlessです。

英文だと、Unless you interrupt statute of limitations by the act of claiming (your money back), you finally lose your claim.